# Apply text configuration to array in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

In PostgreSQL database I have an ARRAY field and right now I am trying to build full text search capabilities for it. But what I noticed that PostgreSQL text configuration is not applied to array content as it is applied to text strings.
For example next query:

```
select 
setweight(array_to_tsvector(ARRAY['crunchy']), 'A'),
setweight(to_tsvector('english', 'crunchy'), 'A')
FROM (VALUES (1)) AS t (num);
```

Produces result:

```
|'crunchy'|'crunchi':1A|
```

Which is surprising as I expected to see identical `'crunchi'` for both cases.

Is there any way to apply `'english'` TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION to every element in the array?

P. S. I think I can use `array_to_string` but it looks a little bit ugly.

Comment: `array_to_string` doesn't sound like ugly to me, You can use a non-printable character as a separator, for instance chr(10)

Comment: Thank you, @Edouard. This is the direction I am heading now. I am just curious if I am missing something. Without SEARCH CONFIGURATION `array_to_tsvector` looks pretty useless.

Comment: array_to_string can't be indexed