# Why in PostgreSQL setweight doesn't set weight for array_to_tsvector?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, ranking, tsvector

In my table I need to create a `tsvector` out of an array of text and then `setweight` it accordingly. But it doesn't seem to work:

```sql
select
    setweight(to_tsvector('simple', 'test vector of multiple values'), 'A') as "simple",
    setweight(to_tsvector('simple', array_to_string(array['test', 'vector', 'of', 'multiple', 'values'], ' ')), 'A') as "string array",
    setweight(array_to_tsvector('{test, vector, of, multiple, values}'::text[]), 'A') as "text array",
    setweight(array_to_tsvector(array['test', 'vector', 'of', 'multiple', 'values']), 'A') as "array"
```

This gives me:

| simple | string array | text array | array |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'multiple':**4A** 'of':**3A** 'test':**1A** 'values':**5A** 'vector':**2A** | 'multiple':**4A** 'of':**3A** 'test':**1A** 'values':**5A** 'vector':**2A** | 'multiple' 'of' 'test' 'values' 'vector' | 'multiple' 'of' 'test' 'values' 'vector' |

Notice the absence of weights in last 2 columns.
Tried to google something about it but the only thing I found was [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761642/apply-text-configuration-to-array-in-postgres) without meaningful comments.

Again, I don't need to index or search an array and `array_to_string` workaround seems a bit ugly to me too (just like the author of the mentioned topic).

What am I missing about `array_to_tsvector`? Or `setweight` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-MANIPULATE-TSVECTOR):

> Note that weight labels apply to positions, not lexemes. If the input vector has been stripped of positions then setweight does nothing.

I don't know what the best work-around is, as I don't know what you are doing.  Setting weights is pointless if you don't do anything with them.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that part. Thanks! I guess this is how it had to be done: `$$'test':1A 'vector':2A 'of':3A 'multiple':4A 'values':5A$$::tsvector`. But looks like using `array_to_string` is much better in the end.